# Why does Cardinality become 1 when I show index?

Tags: mysql, sql, cardinality

Initially, the database monitoring platform had slow sql alerts.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE deduct_status = 1 AND bill_date = '2023-02-15' AND type IN (1, 2) AND gs_id IN (794872, 794873, 794874, 794875, 532720, 794868, 794869, 794870, 794871, 794864);
```

I first queried the information of this table. The table structure is as follows.
**I omitted some irrelevant sensitive fields and comments.**

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
`gs_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`bill_date` date NOT NULL ,
`account_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' ,
`bill_count` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`deduct_status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`deduct_amount` decimal(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`version` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`gmt_create` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`creator` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
`gmt_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `uk_gsid_billdate_type_accountid` (`gs_id`, `bill_date`, `type`, `account_user_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 377270771 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
```

As normal, this sql would query through the unique index **uk_gsid_billdate_type_accountid**.
So, I think maybe there is something wrong with the index. cause mysql's optimizer to choose not to query by index.

Then I executed the following sql.

```
show INDEX from t1;
```

The execution results are as follows,I hide the table name：

[image]

Here is some other information I think useful:

```
SELECT index_name, stat_name, stat_value, stat_description
       FROM mysql.innodb_index_stats WHERE table_name like 't1';
```

[image]

```
show variables like 'innodb_stats%';
```

[image]

```
select  version();
```

[image]

I want to know why CARDINALITY is 1 and if this is the reason for slow sql.

After a night,I re-excuted this sql,This table is back to normal.I didn't do anything.

```
show INDEX from t1;
```

[image]

Comment: `deduct_status` seems to be missing from the table definition.

Answer (score 2):

That index starts with what is probably a low-cardinality `gs_id`.  Furthermore, that column is not tested with `=`, so the Optimizer would get past `gs_id`.

```
WHERE deduct_status = 1
  AND bill_date = '2023-02-15'
  AND type IN (1, 2)
  AND gs_id IN (794872, 794873, ...)
```

The optimal index be something like:

```
INDEX(deduct_status, bill_date,   -- either order is OK
      type, gs_id)                -- again, either order
```

Even so, the cardinality of the first 2 columns may not be sufficient to warrant using the index.

Run `ANALYZE TABLE t1;`; it *may* update the cardinalities.

Comment: I understand what you mean, the index is not differentiated enough, but I would like to know why the CARDINALITY is 1, and how the result is calculated.  I checked the mysql documentation, but I didn't find information about it

Comment: @HuangGuojun - Cardinality is determined by a very few probes into the table, leading to a crude number that is stored for future use.  Cardinality should _not_ be considered when _you_ whether to have `INDEX(a,b)` vs `INDEX(b,a)`